# How to run updated packages from current folder not the site-packages folder

Tags: python, pythonpath

I have some code I've written, and it's saved in the 'standard' package/project folder structure. I've recently added some new functions to one of the packages, but on testing it told me the functions dodn't exist. This was from the command line and from PyDev.

Last week I was playing with packaging and installed (via setuptools) my package on my computer.

So, within PyDev for the current project or from the command line when I do, say, 'from xxx import yyy' it is taking my installed package in preference to the copy I have open in PyDev (or from a command line at the path) and asking it to run. In the case of PyDev it finds the new functions fine, just when running proceeds to fail.

I would have thought the current folder would take precedence over the lib\site-packages folder or PyDev would do the same.

What is the best way of getting this to work, i.e. testing local code rather than the currently installed version?

thanks.

Comment: Why not install the updated version?

Comment: Also, [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) would be really helpful here if you wanted to fine tune something in a controlled environment.

Comment: Because I just want to press Run, not install everything everytime I make a minor change. 

But things just seem to get worse for me. After removing the install all is well, then I modify the code and it fails. Turns out I need to *clean* the project every single time I make a change. I just hate this system. Why can't it just run like say Java or c# ;)

I mean, what is the point in caching code so that when you modify it you can't actually run it unless you delete a pycache folder....

Comment: If you have a module in your current directory that is the first to be loaded.  See here:  https://www.inkling.com/read/learning-python-mark-lutz-4th/chapter-21/the-module-search-path